# Trail Head App Exchange Trail

Tags: trailhead

Challenge Not yet complete... here's what's wrong: 
You don't have permissions to install AppExchange packages in your Developer Edition org. You'll need to edit your permissions so that you can install the AppExchange package.

Comment: I successfully installed the package in my developer org but it shows the above error

Comment: Does your profile have access to install appexchange packages

Answer (score 0):

When you are installing the provide access to all profile
if you are installing lightning package from Salesforce 
then you need need to enable domain in Salesforce then you can use it as component.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.identityImplGuide.meta/identityImplGuide/domain_name_overview.htm